# SGDRegressor nonsensical result

Tags: python, statistics, scikit-learn

I try to make a simple test case for a regression a linear function of x, but the SGDRegressor gives me a wrong result

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from random import random
X = np.array(range(1000))
y = np.array([x + random() for x in X])
X = X.reshape(1000,1)
sgd = SGDRegressor()
sgd.fit(X, y)
print [sgd.intercept_, sgd.coef_]
```

> [array([ -4.13761484e+08]), array([ -9.66320825e+10])]

Comment: what results do you expect ?

Comment: a coefficient of 1 and an intercept of 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it has something to do with the fact that adding `random()` to an int from 0 - 1000 has a small effect on the ints as they get larger. Feature scaling using `StandardScaler` as a preprocessing step might help.

According to Sklearn's *tips on practical use*:

> Stochastic Gradient Descent is sensitive to feature scaling, so it is
>   highly recommended to scale your data.

After tinkering around with your example and NOT using feature scaling, the parameter combinations I noticed that made a difference were: loss, n_iter, eta0, and power_t are ones to focus on - `eta0` being the primary parameter. The SGDRegressor defaults are too high for this problem.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools

X = np.array(range(1000))
y = np.array([x + random() for x in X])
X = X.reshape(-1,1)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(8,6))
coords = itertools.product([0,1], repeat=2)

for coord,loss in zip(coords, ['huber', 'epsilon_insensitive',
                               'squared_epsilon_insensitive', 'squared_loss']):
  row,col = coord
  ax[row][col].plot(X, y, 'k:', label='actual', linewidth=2)
  for iteration in [5, 500, 1000, 5000]: # or try range(1, 11)
    sgd = SGDRegressor(loss=loss, n_iter=iteration, eta0=0.00001, power_t=0.15)
    sgd.fit(X, y)
    y_pred = sgd.intercept_[0] + (sgd.coef_[0] * X)
    print('Loss:', loss, 'n_iter:', iteration, 'intercept, coef:',
          [sgd.intercept_[0], sgd.coef_[0]], 'SSE:', ((y - sgd.predict(X))**2).sum())

    ax[row][col].plot(X, y_pred, label='n_iter: '+str(iteration))
    ax[row][col].legend()
    ax[row][col].set_title(loss)
    plt.setp(ax[row][col].legend_.get_texts(), fontsize='xx-small')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here's what prints out:

```
Loss: huber n_iter: 5 intercept, coef: [0.001638952911639975, 0.81740614500327669] SSE: 11185831.2597
Loss: huber n_iter: 500 intercept, coef: [0.021493133105072931, 1.0006662185561777] SSE: 137.574163486
Loss: huber n_iter: 1000 intercept, coef: [0.037047745354150396, 1.0006161110073943] SSE: 134.784858635
Loss: huber n_iter: 5000 intercept, coef: [0.12718334969902309, 1.0006005570641865] SSE: 116.13213201
Loss: epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 5 intercept, coef: [0.0046948965851395814, 1.0005010438267816] SSE: 157.935817311
Loss: epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 500 intercept, coef: [0.15261696111333306, 0.99963762449395877] SSE: 359.657749786
Loss: epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 1000 intercept, coef: [0.24224930972696881, 1.0006671880072746] SSE: 126.805962732
Loss: epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 5000 intercept, coef: [0.45888370500803022, 1.0003153040071979] SSE: 106.091573864
Loss: squared_epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 5 intercept, coef: [1774329.1447094907, -113423.55986319004] SSE: 4.08404355317e+18
Loss: squared_epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 500 intercept, coef: [42274920.182269663, -104909.90969312852] SSE: 1.01976866207e+18
Loss: squared_epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 1000 intercept, coef: [22843691.320190568, -37289.079052061767] SSE: 1.33664638821e+17
Loss: squared_epsilon_insensitive n_iter: 5000 intercept, coef: [3165399.5624849019, -3391.4406385053994] SSE: 3.12252668162e+15
Loss: squared_loss n_iter: 5 intercept, coef: [0.29805062264896459, 1.0006351157532956] SSE: 131.697873311
Loss: squared_loss n_iter: 500 intercept, coef: [0.66256539671809789, 1.0001831768155882] SSE: 154.277820955
Loss: squared_loss n_iter: 1000 intercept, coef: [0.13753387481588603, 1.0006362052460742] SSE: 117.151466521
Loss: squared_loss n_iter: 5000 intercept, coef: [0.38191334428572482, 1.0000364177730059] SSE: 89.3183008079
```

This is what it looks like plotted (note: this changes each time you re-run so your output might look different from mine):

[image: SGD Loss Responses]

What's interesting to notice is the y-axis for `squared_epsilon_insensitive` shoots into oblivion while the other three loss functions stay within the expected range.

For fun, change `power_t` from **0.15** to **0.5**. The reason this has an effect is the default `learning_rate` parameter is `'invscaling'` computed by `eta = eta0 / pow(t, power_t)`

[image: SGD is a sensitive flower]

Comment: Can you tell what is `t` in `eta = eta0 / pow(t, power_t)`?

Comment: @Rohith.`t` is a [time step](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/sgd.html#id1)

Answer (score 4):

Try setting a lower initial learning rate than the default value `0.01`, for example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
from random import random
X = np.array(range(1000))
y = np.array([x + random() for x in X])
X = X.reshape(1000,1)
sgd = SGDRegressor(eta0=0.000001)
sgd.fit(X, y)
print [sgd.intercept_, sgd.coef_]
```

Output:

```
[array([ 0.00648436]), array([ 1.00053978])]
```

---

Edit: I'm not sure about the exact reason, but the large values contained in `X` and `y` seem to cause some numerical stability issues. Setting `verbose=1` in `SGDRegressor`, it shows the following output with the default learning rate:

```
-- Epoch 1
Norm: nan, NNZs: 1, Bias: nan, T: 1000, Avg. loss: nan
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
```

which means that the internal computation has somehow overflowed. With `eta=0.000001`:

```
-- Epoch 1
Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.006449, T: 1000, Avg. loss: 873.136013
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
-- Epoch 2
Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.006461, T: 2000, Avg. loss: 436.597862
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
-- Epoch 3
Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.006471, T: 3000, Avg. loss: 291.085373
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
-- Epoch 4
Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.006481, T: 4000, Avg. loss: 218.329235
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
-- Epoch 5
Norm: 1.00, NNZs: 1, Bias: 0.006491, T: 5000, Avg. loss: 174.675614
Total training time: 0.00 seconds.
[array([ 0.00649087]), array([ 1.00035165])]
```

Another possible approach is to scale the data (both input and output) to normal ranges beforehand, e.g. using `StandardScaler`. With that preprocessing done, the default parameters worked well.

Comment: could you explain why that helps?